# Creating Multi-Dimensional Dynamic Navigation using Blade in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Ok so i have a nav object that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nav_title] => page title 1
            [parent_id] => 
            [page_url] => /page-title-1
            [top_nav_flag] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [nav_title] => page title 2
                            [parent_id] => 3
                            [page_url] => /page-title-1/page-title-2
                            [top_nav_flag] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [nav_title] => page title 3
                            [parent_id] => 3
                            [page_url] => /page-title-1/page-title-3
                            [top_nav_flag] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [6] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [nav_title] => page title 4
                            [parent_id] => 3
                            [page_url] => /page-title-1/page-title-4
                            [top_nav_flag] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nav_title] => page title 5
            [parent_id] => 
            [page_url] => /page-title-5
            [top_nav_flag] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [8] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [nav_title] => page title 6
                            [parent_id] => 7
                            [page_url] => /page-title-5/page-title-6
                            [top_nav_flag] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [11] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [nav_title] => page title 7
                                            [parent_id] => 8
                                            [page_url] => /page-title-5/page-title-6/page-title-7
                                            [top_nav_flag] => 1
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [9] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [nav_title] => page title 8
                            [parent_id] => 7
                            [page_url] => /page-title-5/page-title-8/
                            [top_nav_flag] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [10] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [nav_title] => page title 9
                            [parent_id] => 7
                            [page_url] => /page-title-5/page-title-9/
                            [top_nav_flag] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

and so forth.

Now what I am trying to do is make it so that I can dynamically use a specific "template" for each nav.  so where normally i would just @foreach through the nav, it won't really work in this case because I have sub navs and I'm looking for a better way than to just @foreach then @if(!empty(children)) sort of deal, I need a way to dynamically pass the nav template to render each nav and sub nav regardless of depth.  in some cases the navigation is simple, each row item is something like:

```
<li>
     <a href="/url">url text</a>
    @if($subNav) <ul> {{ $subNav }} </ul> @endif
</li>
```

and the above $subNav would need to be provided it's own structure though in my case, the structure is identicaly from parent nav to sub nav for each nav row item, the difference only being the sub navs are each nested under their parent inside the parent

tag.

but other times it's a lot more complex like:

```
<li>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <i class="list"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="large-11 columns">
            <input type="text" name="nav[$nav_id]" value="$nav_title">
        </div>
    </div>
    <ol>
        {{ sub nav goes here }}
    </ol>
</li>
```

The other issue here, is that in some cases there is a header/footer specific items so I'll need to add conditionals to this or just re-render the nav again using a different set of data (i.e. filter out the separations in the page controller.

I guess my question is, how would I create such a template extension or what have you to accomplish this?

Comment: Theres alot of menu packages around - why dont you just use one of those?

Comment: I was hoping to learn how to do this to further my skills with Laravel and Blade, and figured this would be a good excursive.  Also the application of this, for what I'm building, would apply to more than just a nav.